# Does Windows end a file transfer after an RDP session times out?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management

If a large local file transfer (intra-system) needs to happen in an environment where RDP will time out if there is no user interaction, can one expect the file transfer to continue after RDP disconnects?

Furthermore, if another user signs in, kicking the RDP session (disconnected or not) to "inactive" state, will this end the file transfer?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Programs should continue to run even if the user is disconnected (very few apps may have problems in this scenario). Only if the user session is terminated programs will stop. Just look at the other users processes in Taskmanager and you will they consume CPU time as they run.

Comment: Thanks Robert, to be sure I'm understanding correctly, when a different user signs on locally or via RDP, and is asked "Another user is signed in. If you continue, they'll be disconnected." -- the session is not *terminated*, just *disconnected*? 

*The verbiage would suggest as much, but just to be sure, a file transfer should continue?

Comment: On Windows 10 it depends on the mode Windows is running, if fast-User switching is enabled the session should stay alive. Just try it out, you should be able to see in taskmanager if a second user session is running.

Comment: Fast user switching isn't enabled in this environment, which I guess is the caveat. However-- RDP sessions that have been disconnected still show up via a `query user`, whether that would sustain a file transfer, I have no idea.

Comment: "Fast user switching isn't enabled in this environment" – I'm pretty sure it cannot be *disabled* in Windows after XP, can it? It can be hidden, but the underlying Terminal Services session support is still there (otherwise you couldn't *have* those multiple sessions in quser/qwinsta). The OS itself relies on TS being present, as Windows since Vista  isolates services to session 0 while putting you in sessions 1+.

Comment: That's interesting info, thanks-- so I guess back to the original question, is it relatively safe to assume a disconnected RDP session will continue to transfer a file locally overnight if I don't *actively sign out*? *disconnect via time-out or another user butting in on the system

Comment: If you connect to the remote system, perform a copy from a remote drive to a remote drive (both local to that system), then it will continue to run in the background unless something on that system interferes. For example, you copy to a network share that is available to that system, but the network connection is dropped, or the computer is rebooted by automatic windows update, or another user uses task manager to kill your process because he sees high CPU usage.